# Use data frame names when creating a list of/from data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names

I have three data frames: `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.

I want to merge them into a list:

```
dataframes <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

How can I use the names of each data frame for their corresponding list element names?

So that instead of this:

```
> names(dataframes)
[1] "" "" ""
```

I get this:

```
> names(dataframes)
[1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name them when creating the list:

```
dataframes <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)

names(dataframes)
#"df1" "df2" "df3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using a loop.  I assume that `df1`, `df2`, and `df3` are data frames, and have been defined somewhere.

```
i <- 1
lst <- list()   # an empty list

while (i <= 3) {
    df_name <- paste0("df", i)
    lst[[i]] <- get(df_name)
    names(lst)[i] <- df_name
    i <- i + 1
}

names(lst)

[1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
```

### Demo

While many view using loops in R as being evil, the above case is not so bad, because we simply add new list items (and their names) one by one, as the loop progresses.